# Why is this giving me error C2661:no overloaded function takes 2 arguments?

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2012, vector

*error C2661: 'Stock::Stock' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments*

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 fyi and I keep getting a C2661 error every time I try to fill a vector with objects of a class:

```
void AFTS::createSys() {
    AFTS::fs.assign(100, new Stock());
    // the error occurs when calling the assign() function
}
```

Here is the class holding the vector:

```
class AFTS {
public:
    std::vector<Stock> fs;
    void createSys();
    void addStock(Stock stock, int price);
    void deleteStock(Stock stock);
    int stockGetPrice(Stock stock);
    void sellStock(Stock stock, int price);
    void buyStock(Stock stock, int min, int max);
};
```

Here is the class i'm trying to fill the vector with:

```
class Stock {
public:
    int price;
    std::string tick;
};
```

At first i thought it could be an error related to including header files but i've checked multiple times and they seem to be correct so I can't quite see what i'm doing wrong to cause this.

Comment: Failing to read the documentation, mostly...

Comment: I'm really not sure how you got _that_ error from this code. Oh well.

Comment: @Quentin: Where exactly is this code attempting to invoke a `Stock` constructor with two arguments?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh, I didn't notice that part of the message was weird. I can't reproduce it with MSVC 2013 (`error C2664: 'void std::vector<Foo,std::allocator<_Ty>>::assign(unsigned int,const Foo &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'Foo *' to 'const Foo &'`). MSVC 2012 bug ?

Comment: @Quentin OP bug more likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop misusing `new`. That's for dynamic allocation, not for every "new" object you make.

You have a container of `Stock` objects, not `Stock*` pointers, so pushing `new Stock` into it is incorrect. At *best*, you'd be creating a vector filled with 100 pointers to the same dynamically-allocated object! C++ ain't Java.

All you need is this:

```
fs.clear();      // may not need this; depends on prior vector use
fs.resize(100);
```

Those elements will be default-constructed.

I've also taken the liberty of removing the redundant `AFTS::` qualifier.

Comment: There we go... Totally forgot that you don't create an object with new.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<Stock> fs;
```

Your vector contains `Stock`s.

```
AFTS::fs.assign(100, new Stock());
```

But you try to insert a `Stock*`.

In any case, one hundred pointers pointing to the same `Stock` is probably bad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you try to insert a pointer instead of an object:

```
std::vector<Stock> fs;
```

You have a simple vector here of object class `Stock`, so it should be filled like:

```
AFTS::fs.assign(100, Stock());
```